# Hibernate = Criteria to query tables

Tags: spring, hibernate

I would like to query hibernate just by passing it an object and I thought this was supported but I guess it isnt as my query returns all the objects in my Product table.

I have a product and a product has a set of categories and I would like to return all products that have that category.

Category is just an id (which I am passing as null as I want to get by name) and a name which is a string which I am setting on the category object, and then passing to the Product object by adding it to a set attached to the product.

I pass an object to the spring rest client and convert this to a hibernate entity and then I thought I could just pass it to hibernate with the properties I want to filter by set:

```
public List<Product> getProductsByFilterCriteria(Product productToLocate) { 
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    //Just maps the values
    ProductEntity criteria = mapProductCriteriaToEntity(productToLocate);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<ProductEntity> productsMatchingCriteria =   (List<ProductEntity>)session.createCriteria(ProductEntity.class).add(Example.create(criteria).excludeZeroes()).list();    

    for(ProductEntity productEntity : productsMatchingCriteria) {

        products.add(mapProductEntityToProduct(productEntity));
    }

    return products;          
}
```

I have set up the product entity with a list which contains a single category, and no other properties are set.

How do I just pass the Product and its set of Categories to hibernate and get out all products which have a Category of whatever the category name is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-examples):

> ### 17.8. Example queries
>
> The class org.hibernate.criterion.Example allows you to construct a query criterion from a given instance.
>
> [...]
>
> Version properties, identifiers and **associations are ignored**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Ok so its not possible to do that then, so what would be the normal way to get all products which have a category of whatever I am searching for? Its a many to many relationship between product and category.

Comment: Using a JPQL query with a join, or a Criteria query with a join: `select p from Product p join p.categories c where c.name = :name`.

Comment: Oh ok, I was trying to avoid using this sort of syntax as I have a rest interface and I mistakenly assumed that I could just build an object and then send it having just a generic end point for query searching but I guess I need to rethink my rest interface and repository design.